Questions about best way to raise the handlebar on my bike
I recently bought a hybrid bike and I'm not comfortable with my body position when riding it. It feel like I'm leaning too far forward and would prefer to be more upright so I want to raise the handlebars. The bike is a Carrera Subway 2 Mens Hybrid Bike XL .
I've never done any changes/upgrades to bikes in the past, so am pretty inexperienced with this.
I've been looking into it a bit and have seen that there are two options:

a handlebar riser, like this:  Steerer tube extension source link
an adjustable stem riser like this:
Halfords source link

Is there any consensus on which is the preferred option? Are there pros/cons to each? I'd be very grateful for any help.
Thanks



You have had some great answers. From a cost perspective, you may find that replacing the handlebars with riser bars is the cheapest and arguably easiest option, and allows you to choose a new shape that might better suit your hands eg. backsweep, but would only allow for a limited amount of rise compared to the stem options.

Do keep in mind that will reduce pedaling efficiency as Your center of mass will be moved rearward. In Your shoes I would explore the issue deeper - starting with the major problem - do hands hurt?, or the spine?, or handling is sluggish? etc.

Thanks @Vorac The main issue is my neck starts hurting because I am leaning forward but need to look upwards, so I need to raise my neck.
The hands hurt a little bit from pressure on the handlebar but that isn't the major issue.

First a couple of notes: double check all dimensions and read up on fitting stems (a simple enough task, if you do the right things in the right order).
Now, both products have their uses.
The adjustable stem is sometimes used to dial in a fit before replacing with a fixed one of the right length/angle, but it can be left on.  Changing the angle brings the bars closer to you as well as higher, and closer also makes your sitting position more upright.  This means that although the total height gain is fairly small, the effect can be quite big.  You can set it to closely (subject to overall length) mimic your existing setup, and then test incremental movements
That stem riser would appear to provide a minimum of 58mm of rise.  That's quite a big jump from where you are now.  I'm rather wary of mystery brands on Amazon for safety-critical components, but the basic design is standard; I have one on the tandem.
Only you know how far you think you want to raise the bars, so you'll need to choose based on that information. You could even use both!
It's not totally clear from your top-down photo, but I assume that there's no, or just one thin spacer above the stem.  Otherwise the first thing to try would be setting the stem as high as it goes with the hardware you've got.
You may want to look into home bike fitting techniques but in this case I don't recommend a professional bike fit.. That will sound wrong to some, but:

For a new rider on a Halfords hybrid, a proper bike fit is overkill - it would probably cost more than the bike.
A shop fitting from Halfords is something to be avoided based on the experience of everyone I know who's had one from their barely-trained sales staff.
A new (or returning after a long break) rider will either not ride enough to benefit, or ride enough that they'll change posture and flexibility quickly, making the fit out of date fast.


Thanks @Chris H. I've added in a new photo from the side.


Is there any consensus on which is the preferred option?

Neither.
The preferred option is a stem with the correct length and angle. There are typically 6 or 7 degree stems, 17 degree stems and 35 degree stems. Stems can also be flipped facing up or facing down, so with these three stems, you have six options for the amount of rise.
Stem adjustments are made by doing coarse adjustment by selecting the stem: 6 or 6/7 degrees, 17 degrees, 35 degrees. If you pick 17 or 35 degrees, you probably have an idea whether you're going to flip it up or down. For 6/7 degrees, either up or down is an option, and you may be unsure which you want to do. Bikes usually come with 6/7 degree stem.
Fine adjustments are doing by moving the spacers either below or above the stem.
If you don't know at all which handlebar height you prefer, you can buy an adjustable stem, but even then you have to have an idea of the correct length of the stem.
Adjustable stems are intended only for temporary use, and don't allow adjusting length (except by changing the angle and spacer positions at the same time, but this makes only very minor adjustments).
Once you have the fit dialed in, you almost certainly want to ditch the adjustable stem and buy a stem with the correct angle and length.

Concur - adjustable stems are good for working out what you want.  Some can even be adjusted for length as well as angle.

Thanks @juhist.
Sorry for the noob question, I have no experience at all with bike alterations so want to make sure I understand what you're saying. When you say "buy a stem with the correct angle and length." do you mean something like this https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/stems/ram-1-18-inch-ahead-stem-35-deg-318mm-clamp-black-165mm/. Thanks

What neither juhist nor @Criggie says is why they'd want to replace an adjustable stem with a fixed one in this case.  On my bikes that are expected to go a long way or over rough terrain, I'd swap to a fixed stem - marginally lighter and a bit more robust.  But on the old hybrid I keep here, the only reason to remove the adjustable stem it came with would be to use it somewhere else.  For light duty they're fine, no need to buy yet another part.

@user3091576 basically, yes.  The adjustable can help you dial in a good comforable fit, and then you take measurements and get a fixed stem about the same but lighter and more secure.  That single central pivot is not robust in the long term or for a lot of riding.

@Criggie That single central pivot is not robust in the long term or for a lot of riding.  I'd also be at least a little bit worried about hitting a solid bump when I just happen to have the handlebars fully loaded with my weight, causing that pivot to break free.  And that could happen just 10 seconds into the first ride with the stem.

There are typically 6 or 7 degree stems, 17 degree stems and 35 degree stems. 45-degree stems also exist - I have one.  I think they're meant for track use to get very low bars, but the could always be flipped to get a bit more height.  Then there's this:  https://www.amazon.com/ergotec-Humpert-Charisma-Adaptor-Aluminium/dp/B006519964?th=1&psc=1

There are other options to change the cockpit geometry than to make the stem higher.

A shorter stem. Chosing a stem that is 1-3 cm shorter already leads to a less streched and more upright position. Maybe you don't actually have to rise anything.
A handlebar with rise. Some bars are completely flat, but you can easily get MTB bars with 30-50mm rise (or more)
Handlebar backsweep. Most bars are slightly angled backwards by just a few degrees, but you can find basically everything up to 90° (which of course would be far too much)


First and foremost, always make sure to get things set to the right torque when reassembling things after modifications to your headset. This is especially important for the bolt that compresses the stem and headset against the top of the head tube, because it’s what provides the correct preload for your headset and crown bearings. Too much there and you’ll wear them out fast, too little and your fork will wobble. Note that this means you really need to be using a torque wrench for this, and know what torque settings are involved. If you don’t know what any of that means, I strongly suggest consulting your local bike store (they should at least be able to point you at the right type of tools and help you figure out torque settings when they’re not printed on the parts).
Second, avoid steerer tube extenders. They have a strong tendency to slip, which then means you have to realign your handlebars. In theory this might not matter if you are only doing very light riding, but they’re definitely not acceptable for heavy duty usage and I would always consider getting a new stem with a longer steerer tube first.
Adjustable stems, on the other hand, absolutely can be acceptable for light to moderate usage. The one you’ve listed is actually a relatively common one, and one of the very few designs I would trust. It is especially important if you choose to use one of these to get the torque setting correct on the bolt that holds the angle adjustment in place, not getting it tight enough will run a very real risk of a hard landing or large bump in the road causing it to slip. If you’re looking at heavy riding, I would also avoid these except to possibly figure out the optimal positioning.
Alternatives to those include:

It’s not really possible to tell from your picture, but if there are spacers above the stem on the steerer tube, simply moving those below the stem will raise the handlebars and give you a more upright position. This is unlikely to get you a significant improvement though unless there are a lot of them to move.
New handlebars. Handlebar geometry can vary significantly, and just getting different handlebars may be enough to help here. If you want a more upright position, look for either more backsweep (the angle the handlebars bend backwards towards the rider) or more rise (the elevation of the grips relative to the stem). MTB or BMX handlebars are likely your best bet for finding either of those properties (or both).
Just get a shorter fixed stem with a more aggressive angle. What you have currently looks like either a straight stem, or a 6-7 degree stem. You should be able to pretty easily find a 17 or 35 degree stem, and it shouldn’t be all that difficult to find a shorter one as well, and both of those changes will bring the handlebars closer to you.
Depending very heavily on the bike geometry, you may be able to move the saddle forwards or downwards, both of which will inherently give you a slightly more upright position. Note though that going more than about a centimeter in either direction from your ‘optimal’ position for pedaling will start to interfere with your ability to pedal efficiently, so this should only really be used for very minute adjustments.
Mentioning this just for completeness, since it’s absurdly expensive, but there’s always the BMB Raised Reversed Stem. They look absolutely ridiculous and defy conventional wisdom about bike geometry (though this is a case where conventional wisdom is not entirely accurate), but using one will definitely get you a more upright riding position.


Thanks @austin-hemmelgarn, I really appreciate your feedback.
Regarding the torque settings, I don't really know what you are talking about as my experience is very limited but my plan is to get Halfords to do the fitting for me. Hopefully they'll know what to do?
Regarding this "The one you’ve listed is actually a relatively common one, and one of the very few designs I would trust" are you referring to the one from Halfords (https://www.halfords.com/cycling/bike-parts/headsets-stems/bikehut-adjustable-alloy-stem-357335.html)?
I've also added in a new side view picture. Thanks

@user3091576 Put simply, you need to make sure that certain bolts/nuts on the bike are sufficiently tight, but not too tight. The amount of force applied when tightening is known as torque, and it’s usually measured in newton-meters (Nm) or foot-pounds (ft. lbf.). Exact target numbers depend on the specific parts involved, though they’re often not too hard to look up (and sometimes they’re printed on the parts themselves, like with that adjustable stem you linked to). The tricky part here is that special (and unfortunately somewhat expensive) tools are needed to get things right.
